# How tag A generated in a site with SharePoint

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sharepoint

There is a tag A with below code gets generated in a site developed with SharePoint:

`<a class="ms-cui-ctl-large" id="SaveAndClose" 
onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;" mscui:controltype="Button" role="button" unselectable="on">
</a>`

I want to know how the **onClick="return false;"** is generated(and I want to change this behavior), but don't find it.
For me, seems it's automatically generated based on some button/menuitem. But I don't see any code to set the value for onClick.

Can anybody show me how SharePoint(or ASP.NET) create such a hyperlink tag? How can I change this **onClick** attribute?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Sharepoint hyperlink tag

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("Yoursitename"))

        {

            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())

            {

                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("HyperLink");

                if (list != null)

                {

                    SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();

                    SPFieldUrlValue hyper = new SPFieldUrlValue();

                    hyper.Description = "Stack overflow";

                    hyper.Url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

                    item["Title"] = "New item";

                    item["Hyper"] = hyper;

                    item.Update();                       

                }

            }

        }
```

changing onclick attribute- an example below

```
 onclick="Yourfunction();return false;"

function Yourfunction()
{
//your code 
return false;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are any other controls will generate a hyper link on final html page? Seems it don't use SPFieldUrlValue at all.
And, **how** to change the onClick attribute via code?

Comment: I am aware of SPFieldUrlValue which I have used above in the code. For Onclick attribute, I have added an example for java-script code above, in that way you can use.

Comment: Sure, I could use the javascript like that, the question is **how/where** to add the code **"function(); return false"** to the **onClick** attribute? Sorry, I'm new to this...

Comment: you can use that on asp page. This (onclick="Yourfunction();return false;") is calling the YourFunction function which you have defined in the form of javascript